# "At sign" @ in SimpleXML object?

Tags: php, simplexml

This is the output of `print_r()` run on a typical SimpleXMLElement object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (

        )
)
```

What does the @ sign mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object.  The '@attributes' row is an internal representation of the [attributes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) from the XML element.  Use SimpleXML's functions to get data from this object rather than interacting with it directly.

Comment: I don't know why.  SimpleXML decided to name the array element that, I guess.

Comment: @Rocket I can't find a way to include @ in a variable name

Comment: You can use `${'@var'}` to make a variable with '@' in the name.  In the case of Objects you can do `$obj->{'@var'}`.  SimpleXMLElements are accessed differently, though.  Read the links in the answer.

Comment: This is not an "array". Neither is it an "array element". It's just some internal thingy. Also, it is **not** "all the attributes". For instance, namespaced attributes won't appear in this list. Just don't use `print_r()` on SimpleXMLElement, it's not the appropriate tool.

Comment: @Josh: ah, ok.  I don't know how to use SimpleXMLElement objects, I was just reading that object literally.

Comment: Thanks guys. And thank you for your follow-up questions cambraca.

Comment: incorrect {'@var'} will not return anything, you need to get the obj ($obj) that has the "@var" and use $obj["var"]

Comment: @Pete: First off, the object in this question is a [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object.  You *don't* access it's properties directly, you use it's methods to access data.  Second, if `$obj` is an object, you don't use `[]` to access it's values, you use `->`.  Third, `{'@var'}` is correct when dealing with objects or variable names, array keys don't need the `{}`.  Please see: [http://ideone.com/COYDf](http://ideone.com/COYDf).

Answer (score 9):

All those answers about error control are incorrect. The @ doesn't mean **anything**. That's how the property is called internally, but **do not rely on this**. Do not rely on `print_r()` or `var_dump()` when dealing with SimpleXML. SimpleXML does a lot of "magical" things that are not correctly represented by `print_r()` and `var_dump()`.

If you need to know what's "inside" a XML fragment, just use `->asXML()` on it.

Comment: Yeah, it seems SimpleXMLElement objects are weird.

Comment: You can unselect your previous choice whenever you want to change the accepted answer. It kind of helps the site against turning into a giant race where random people post random answers on subjects they don't know, only to delete them and edit them later when it turns out their random answer was incorrect.

Comment: For better replacements for `print_r` and friends in this situation, have a look at github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't comment as a guest but for anyone else who ends up here like I did... I am creating my own Joomla form fields and Joomla creates a very 'interesting' object of all sorts of things. Now, I didn't want to become a SimpleXML expert, all I wanted was the original label text which was squirrelled away in @attributes.

After a bit of `"hmmm, I wonder if this works?"™` I found this is the easiest way of accessing these values:

```
var_dump($simpleXMLObject);

/* Result */
object(SimpleXMLElement)
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'awesome'
      'label' => string 'Awesome Label'
      'type' => string 'typeOfAwesome'

echo $simpleXMLObject->attributes()->label; // Awesome Label

$simpleXMLObject->attributes()->label = 'Different Day, Different Awesome';
echo $simpleXMLObject->attributes()->label; // Different Day, Different Awesome
```

They were not lying. It really is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with an HTTP API that gives out only XML formatted data. So first I loaded it into SimpleXML and was also puzzled by the @attributes issue.. how do I get at the precious data it contains? **print_r()** confused me.

My solution was to *create an array* and an *iterator variable* at 0. Loop through a SimpleXML object with foreach and get at the data with the attribues() method and load it into my created array. Iterate before foreach loop ends.

So print_r() went from showing this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [First] => John
            [Last] => Smith
        )
)
```

To a much more usable normal array. Which is great because I wanted the option to quickly convert array into json if needed.

My solution in code:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($apiXmlData);
$fugly = $obj->Deeply->Nested->XML->Data->Names;
$people = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($fugly as $val)
{
  $people[$i]['id'] += $val->attributes()->ID;
  $people[$i]['first'] = "". $val->attributes()->First;
  $people[$i]['last'] = "". $val->attributes()->Last;
  $i++;
}
```

Quick note would be PHP's settype() function is weird/buggy, so I added the **+** to make sure ID is an *integer* and added the **quotes** to make sure the name is *string*. If there isn't a variable conversion of some kind, you're going to be loading SimpleXML objects into the array you created.

Final result of print_r():

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first] => John
        [last] => Smith
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [first] => Jane
        [last] => Doe
    )
)
```

Comment: Not answers this questions. To read attributes, you must use array like syntax - instead of `name->attribute`, use `name['attribute']`