# How to call XML data in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple program to CRUD node and node values of xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906073/a-simple-program-to-crud-node-and-node-values-of-xml-file)

I tried calling the data in my XML in the below way. But it didn't work for me. Can anybody tell me how can I make it work?

```
<broad>
    <site>
        <title>My Site Name</title>
        <caption>My Site Caption</caption>
        <hostname>www.mydomain.com</hostname>
    </site>
<broad>
```

My PHP file is

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('settings.xml');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title><?php echo $xml->title; .'|'. $xml->caption; ?></title>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why the above way is not working? is there any other way which is more easier than this?

Comment: First at all delete the first ';' because ';' will break echo statment and you want to concat with caption

Comment: You are missing the 'broad' and 'site' I believe. Probably $xml->broad->site->title will work. In any case a var_dump($xml); will reveal the structure

Comment: Yeah @scott - Calling as $xml->site->title; helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the `site` node:

```
<?php echo (string) $xml->site->title?>
```

If ever in doubt, use a [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; var_dump($xml); echo '</pre>'; ?>
```

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc will **not** tell you all that is in a SimpleXML object for anything other than the simplest XML, due to the large amount of "magic" built into the SimpleXML module. I've written [some specific debug functions](https://github.com/imsop/simplexml_debug) for use with more complex XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<?php echo (string)$xml->site->title .'|'. (string)$xml->site->caption; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleXML debug with `var_dump()` and `print_r()`

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that `var_dump`, `print_r`, etc will **not** tell you all that is in a SimpleXML object for anything other than the simplest XML, due to the large amount of "magic" built into the SimpleXML module. I've written [some specific debug functions](https://github.com/imsop/simplexml_debug) for use with more complex XML.