# Getting value that is prepended with '@' in SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this line of code:

```
print_r($item->figure->iframe);
```

Which produces  this output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [height] => 288
            [mozallowfullscreen] => true
            [src] => http://www.hulu.com/embed.html?eid=Bq_uuy5X4KWFpYZgwa9e9g
            [allowfullscreen] => true
            [width] => 512
            [frameborder] => 0
            [scrolling] => 0
            [webkitAllowFullScreen] => true
        )

)
```

I then try this:

```
var_dump($item->figure->iframe->{'@attributes'}["src"]);
```

Which then gives me this:

```
NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to get the `src` item, why can't I get it?

Comment: Using the class `SimpleXMLElement` without first reading the documentation is also wrong.

Comment: Also [***see here***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327873/at-sign-in-simplexml-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var_dump($item->figure->iframe->attributes());
```

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php