# Call a PHP Value with @ in Front

Tags: php, arrays

How do I call Array value that has @ in front like @activePropertyCount[]

Tried with echo $value[HotelList][@activePropertyCount];

There is an attribute associated with the array e.g HotelSummary - how do I call that if so ?

The code looks like:

```
Array
(
[HotelListResponse] => Array
    (
        [customerSessionId] => 0ABAAABC-3DA4-3914-B842-7B403B905AF7
        [numberOfRoomsRequested] => 1
        [moreResultsAvailable] => 1
        [cacheKey] => 793da43:14b847b403b:-5a8d
        [cacheLocation] => 10.186.170.188:7300
        [cachedSupplierResponse] => Array
            (
                [@supplierCacheTolerance] => MED_ENHANCED
                [@cachedTime] => 0
                [@supplierRequestNum] => 931
                [@supplierResponseNum] => 20
                [@supplierResponseTime] => 1501
                [@candidatePreptime] => 314
                [@otherOverheadTime] => 53
                [@tpidUsed] => 5110
                [@matchedCurrency] => true
                [@matchedLocale] => true
            )
```

Comment: Did you try surrounding it with quotes?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["At sign" @ in SimpleXML object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327873/at-sign-in-simplexml-object)

Comment: worked with quotes around ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the array keys in quotes:

```
echo $value['HotelList']['@activePropertyCount'];
```

This should be done even if you don't expect special characters, because otherwise PHP is looking for a constant at first, then falls back to a string if none found. Whilst this would work on `HotelList`, it won't on `@activePropertyCount` because the @ is a syntax error if unquoted.