# How To Add Additional Field Mappings To Code Pulling from Third Party API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am working with the Church Community Builder API ([official docs](http://designccb.s3.amazonaws.com/helpdesk/files/official_docs/api.html), search for "group profile" to see relevant code) and with [CCB Core WordPress Plugin](https://github.com/jaredcobb/ccb-core) to sync groups data from the API into custom post types (fields, taxonomies).

CCB Core maps a lot of this data automatically, but it doesn't map the group ID value CCB uses to distinguish one group from another and I'd like to sync it.

The relevant code is kept in the functions [get_groups_custom_fields_map()](https://github.com/jaredcobb/ccb-core/blob/master/admin/class-ccb-core-cpts.php#L228) and [get_groups_taxonomy_map()](https://github.com/jaredcobb/ccb-core/blob/master/admin/class-ccb-core-cpts.php#L316).

I've tried adding something like the following to get_groups_taxonomy_map():

```
'group_id' => array (
   'api_mapping' => 'group',
   'data_type' => 'integer',
),
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions on writing code to pull in this field?

UPDATE 9/10/16 7:25 PM:

I think I am wicked close.

I took the XML from the API documentation under Group Profile and ran it through simplexml and [generated this output](https://gist.github.com/davidshq/084f7abf49066f1a3cd0275032406b64).

I then compared the output with how the get_groups_custom_fields_map and get_groups_custom_taxonomy_map was organized, which led me to believe the following should work:

```
        'group' => array (
            'api_mapping' => 'group',
            'data_type' => 'object',
            'child_object' => array(
                'api_mapping' => '@attributes',
                'data_type' => 'object',
                'child_object' => array(
                    'group_id' => array(
                        'api_mapping' => 'id',
                        'data_type' => 'integer'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
```

But it doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleXML representation of the response that comes back from CCB just so happens to have a really frustrating way of deserializing the IDs for the entities (Groups, Events, Individuals, etc) that come out of the API. (And it only happens on the IDs).

Even though Group ID *looks like* a property in the XML response string, it's actually an *attribute* which is slightly different. In your object response, notice that `@` symbol in the `[@attributes]` node. PHP will not allow direct access to that.

See ["At sign" @ in SimpleXML object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327873/at-sign-in-simplexml-object)

As a workaround I actually obtain the Group ID like so right here:
https://github.com/jaredcobb/ccb-core/blob/1a6e88b47ad7d5293e88bac277e72cbc4e33a602/admin/class-ccb-core-sync.php#L589-L595

Code snippet of the above reference:

```
$group_id = 0;
foreach( $group->attributes() as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $key == 'id' ) {
        $group_id = (int) $value;
        break;
    }
}
```

So in general, we **do** have access to that group id, we just need to now save it as post meta. I'll update the plugin to take advantage of these IDs, but in the mean time you can use the `$group_id` variable directly and save the post meta in this function.